# Building dynamic sql query with between and order by key word

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a situation where parameter to my sql query would be dynamic.if parameter is null i don't want to add it to the query,I have tried some thing(never worked)..and it look like stoopid to me now

```
  ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(GlobalSettings.DbDSN, CommandType.Text, "SELECT TOP 1000 [ID],[Project],[Owner],[Consultant],[Contractor],[Value],[Level1],[Level2] ,[Status] ,[Category]  ,[Country],[CreatedDate],[CreatedByID],[CreatedByName] FROM [tbl_Projects] where"+if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(paraCategory)){ "[Category] = @Category  and"}+"+ Country =@country and "+if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(paraCategory)){ " value between @val1 and @val2"}+" order by CreatedDate asc",
                                     new SqlParameter("@Category", paraCategory),
                                      new SqlParameter("@Country", paraCountry),
                                       new SqlParameter("@val1", paraValue1),
                                                        new SqlParameter("@val2", paraValue2));
```

I have checked Building dynamic sql also 
[here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20815/Building-Dynamic-SQL-In-a-Stored-Procedure)
But it is not usefull where I need to put like and between key words..can any one give me a hand on this?

Comment: This looks like C# to me. Could you please tag your question accordingly?

Comment: @FabianBigler Yes I had added some C# code to my sql query to handle this..which was foolishnes..Now I am trying to solve this through sql itself..thats the reason of this post.and I had edited the tags too as you told..if the solution is only with c# I don't want to miss it

Comment: OK. I hope my answer helps you out. It is actually pretty simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give you an idea, I would do something like this:

```
var sql as new StringBuilder();
sql.Append("SELECT ... all your columns ... FROM yourTable");
var parameters as new List(Of SqlParameter);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(paraCategory)
{
  sql.Append("[Category]=@Category,");
  parameters.AddWithvalue("@Category", paraCategory);
}
sql.Length -= 1

//...your other parameters...

sql.Append("ORDER BY CreatedDate");
```

And then pass it all to your SqlHelper:

```
ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(GlobalSettings.DbDSN, CommandType.Text, sql.ToString(), parameters);
```

Also note that the above code is not really defensive. So for example if no parameter is delivered it will fail. And since I don't know the SqlHelper-Class, you might need to have something else than a List(Of SqlParameter).

Comment: You could simply overload `ExecuteDataset` so that you could omit the `parameters`parameter when not needed.

Comment: I am not sure but,this code is not working inside my c# file..Mainly this line 
 var parameters as new List(Of SqlParameter);
Do I need to add any namespace xtra?

Comment: Yes. NameSpace System.Text for StringBuilder.
And System.Collections.Generic for List(Of SqlParameter)

Answer (score 1):

Change `SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset`so that it takes a delegate to call the specific code you want:

```
class SqlHelper
{
    public delegate void SqlCommandDelegate(SqlCommand command);

    public Dataset ExecuteDataset(string dsn, 
            CommandType commandType, 
            SqlCommandDelegate specificPreparations)
    {
        Dataset results;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = dsn;
            using (SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandType = commandType;
                connection.Open();
                specificPreparations(command);
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                results.Load(reader);
            }
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

Then to call it:

```
ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(GlobalSettings.DbDSN, 
    CommandType.Text,
    delegate(SqlCommand command)
    {
        command.CommandText = "SELECT BLAH FROM BLAH";

        foreach (var myParameter in myParameterList)
        {
            SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter();
            // Construct p
            command.Paramters.Add(p)
        }
        // Anything else you want to do to the command
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using a SP

```
    CREATE  PROCEDURE MyDynamicSP(@Condition1 as varchar(100),Condition2 as varchar(100),Condition3 as varchar(100))
    AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @STRSQL VARCHAR(1000)

    SET @STRSQL = 'SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE '
    IF NOT @Condition1 IS NULL
        @STRSQL = @STRSQL + ' ' + @Condition1

    IF NOT @Condition2 IS NULL
        @STRSQL = @STRSQL + ' ' + @Condition2

    IF NOT @Condition3 IS NULL
        @STRSQL = @STRSQL + ' ' + @Condition3

    EXEC sp_executesql @STRSQL

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the testing inside the query as such :

```
SELECT *whatever you need*
    FROM [tbl_Projects] 
    where 
        (@Category is null or [Category] = @Category)  and
        (@Country is null or [Country] = @country) and 
        (@val1 is null or value > @val1) and 
        (@val2 is null or value < @val2)    
    order by CreatedDate asc
```

And you always send the 4 parameters. On the plus side, you can build your query in a SQL worksheet and it's easier to spot syntax errors an so on.

You might need to add some tests for what would be an empty value, though.